# PHP ZipArchive::open always results in an ZIPARCHIVE::ER_READ error

Tags: php, linux, zip

I am currently storing lots of photos in a zip archive on a LAMP server. When a new user gets added to my program I open the zip archive and add their photo.

The problem is when the zip archive approaches 50MB the function ZipArchive::open always returns the error number 5, which I believe is this error ZIPARCHIVE::ER_READ

Does any one have a clue why this would happen?

Many thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I stopped using the ZipArchive class and zipped the files up on the command line using the php exec command http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
exec('tar -cvf file.tar myfile.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing php's `memory_limit`. It's possible it's running out of memory when loading a larger .zip file.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply. I raised the memory_limit to 999M but I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: @TheoKouzelis: Just out of curiosity, if you download the .zip to your computer does it unzip properly?

Comment: Yeah it downloads fine and opens fine

Comment: @TheoKouzelis: In that case the only thing I can find is http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php#92559 which sounds exactly like what you're running into. Are you on a 5.2.x version of PHP?

Comment: Yeah its running on PHP Version 5.2.4 . Yeah I saw that too, I was kind of hoping that wasn't the case. Thanks for all your help though

Comment: @TheoKouzelis: Yeah looking around now it seems there are some other questions here about this issue. It may be worth looking into other zip creation classes (I use the one from phpmyadmin). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Also try to increase `max_execution_time`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply too. I also raised the max_execution_time to 10000 but still the same error